# Send email from other smtp in yii2

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I use swiftmailer to send email from yii2. I get code from websites, but most of them send email from gmail.com. I want to send email from my university email, but it's not working. What's the problem. This is the code:

In main-local.php

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => /*true*/false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.students.del.ac.id',
                'username' => 'if414024@students.del.ac.id',
                'password' => 'bmelar28',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
],
```

Comment: try to remove `smtp` in host like `'host' => 'students.del.ac.id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `smtp` in `'host' => students.del.ac.id`

show below code

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'students.del.ac.id',
            'username' => 'if414024@students.del.ac.id',
            'password' => 'bmelar28',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',                               
        ]
]
```

Comment: It's success. But, how if I use username: paket@del.ac.id? I use host: del.ac.id but I can't send the email.

Comment: I got this error: Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 172.21.2.30 (172.21.2.30:25), connect error 10060
"

Answer (score 0):

Try this : change port number and host

```
'mailer' => [
                'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
                'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
                // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
                // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
                // for the mailer to send real emails.
                'useFileTransport' => /*true*/false,
                'transport' => [
                    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                    'host' => 'students.del.ac.id',
                    'username' => 'if414024@students.del.ac.id',
                    'password' => 'bmelar28',
                    'port' => '25',
                    'encryption' => 'tls',
                ],
    ],
```

Comment: How if I use this: paket@del.ac.id and the host: del.ac.id? I got this error: Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 172.21.2.30 (172.21.2.30:25), connect error 10060
"

Comment: Try once by changing 'port' => '25'